# Security interceptor in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, ws-security, jax-rpc

I'm trying to implement security interceptor in Spring boot application. I have added `XwsSecurityInterceptor`. I have defined customized password validation call back handler. I have defined the policy configuration as provided in attachment. But getting below exception after running my spring boot application:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: xwss:JAXRPCSecurity is not a recognized definition type

How to resolve this exception?

Expecting to add method wise interceptor